# What does やい mean?

Tags: meaning, dialects

Someone ended their sentence with やいな. What dialect is this? What does やい mean? I assume that な means the same thing as in standard Japanese?

**Update:** the original sentence was 「もう出来あがり？仕事はやいな～」.

Comment: Please add some examples.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I believe I recall Ippei in ALWAYS三丁目の夕日 using this... Google tells me it was 「来るったら、来るやい!」-- in reference to Santa.

Comment: Someone said this to me. もう出来あがり？仕事はやいな～

Comment: that's 速い(はやい) ^^;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: This is not an instance of やい, but rather 速い【はやい】, so the information in my original answer is not actually applicable in this case.

---

[Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%9A%E5%A4%9A%E5%BC%81) suggests that at the very least, this is a feature of **Hakata dialect** (though it is also likely a feature of other dialects as well, as suggested by my comment above). In Hakata dialect, it is used as a light suggestion/command, like the ～て form of verbs in other dialect:

> - 「やい」(軽い命令)
>     動詞の連用形に接続。「やれ」の転化したもの。
>     例
>
>   - 「ちょっとあそこを見て」→「ちいとあすこば見やい」

な would then be the same as in standard Japanese, as you assumed.

Comment: Sounds like a large part of this answer should be in the question, not the answer... I don't see @language hacker's comment anywhere. If it was made in private, the question should have been edited accordingly... I'll make the edits, hope that's ok.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, thanks. Should've thought of that.

Comment: やい in the example 来るやい in your comment on the quesiton is used when the speaker states something resolutely (sense [2] in [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82%84%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=119545200000)), and it is different from the やい in the Hakata dialect which signifies the light imperative.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Yeah, I meant it was a different やい by my "other dialects" note, but I suppose that wasn't really very clear.

Comment: やい!たい!ばい! Anyone from Fukuoka here?

Answer (score 1):

When used not as a suffix, but as a stand-alone word, やい is a (rude) attention-getter among children, like the British "Oi", but specific to kids. (Adults would use おい！)

Kids: やい、俺のガンダムを勝手にいじるな！ (Hey, don't mess with my Gundam toy!)

Adults: おい、おれの新車に触るんじゃねえ！ (Hey, don't touch my new car!)

I believe the above is the most common usage (標準語) usage of やい, though as others have noted, some dialects have their own uses for the word.

PS: I thought I'd answer the question as asked in the title, ignoring the fact that it was inspired by a mis-parsed "速い" :)

Comment: I've also heard やい used as a taunt (like `nerr nerr`). や～い！　や～い！

Comment: True, but since "やい！やい！" wouldn't work as a taunt, I tend to think of やい as a distinct word from やーい, which would.