# What does ちょちょい mean?

Tags: slang, definitions, meaning

I can't find this defined anywhere.

Here's an example:

タオルケットをちょちょいかけにきてくれる。

I am also interested in what this whole sentence says.

Comment: I repeat the [same comment as before](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1657/what-does-mean): please add examples.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: I think your example is ungrammatical unless it's meant to be for some minor dialect.

Comment: I suppose these tweets http://www.curated.by/ento/-2 constitute the full context of the example sentence. The tweeter (マオ) is from Fukuoka: [wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%89_(%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89)#.E3.83.A1.E3.83.B3.E3.83.90.E3.83.BC)

Comment: Yes, that is all correct. So what does the whole sentence say?

Comment: I tried [asking him directly](http://twitter.com/#!/ento/status/88938603555733504) but no response so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a variation of ちょっと, but usually in reference to an action. Just like ちょっと in that context, it's meant to indicate that the action will be quick and easy. It's more casual (and therefore more emphatically quick and easy) than ちょっと.

Not that it's rude, but I wouldn't use it outside of casual company.

Comment: So what does the example in my question say?

Comment: "I'll go put the blanket on (somebody)" (タオルケット = a blanket with towel-like texture). The ちょちょい implies that it'll take just a sec, and the speaker will be right back.

Comment: @SuperElectric: Is it not referring to the 先生, that he (kindly) comes and put a blanket on me (the speaker)?

Comment: I hadn't read the original tweet that was linked from the question. You're right, @fnokke, it means "The teacher comes and puts the blanket on me", with ちょちょい meaning that it was done casually, as in, no big deal.

Comment: Although all of this applies to ちょちょいと, I do not think that ちょちょい without と can be used as an adverb (as in the question) in the standard dialect.  As sawa commented on the question, I suspect that it is a dialect-specific usage.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: My theory was wrong, as pointed out by SuperElectric.

---

Maybe it means the same as ちょいちょい ?

That is a Kansai dialect word, translates to: sometimes/often

Example:
サッカーは最近ちょいちょいやってる。
= Recently I have been playing soccer relatively often.

Comment: If I google ちょいちょい then it comes up with a lot of things. Is it the same word?

Comment: I don't know, but I guess it could a variation on the word, with the same meaning. I also see ちょいちょいちょちょい and ちょちょいのちょい being used, sounds like the Spanish construction of `poquiquiquito`.

Comment: This ちょいちょい is more like a Kansai version of しょっちゅう (frequently), and is different from the ちょちょい as used in the question's example.